# Laravel, how to create an article reader count on a blog using cookies

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have a script like this :

```
<?
    public function read($slug, $read_more) {
        $artikel     = App\Post::where('read_more', $read_more)->first();
        $comments    = App\Comment::where('post_id', $artikel->id)->where('active', '1')->get();
        $pops        = App\Post::orderBy('count', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
        $coms        = App\Comment::orderBy('active', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
        $categorys   = App\Category::all();
        $title       = 'Artikel ' . $artikel->category->category . ' &raquo; ' . $artikel->title;
        $description = str_limit($artikel->content, 70);
        $keywords    = $artikel->category->category . ', teknologi, komputer, artikel, pemrograman, informasi, terbaru, linux';
        $view        = view('guest.read', compact('artikel', 'comments', 'categorys', 'title', 'description', 'keywords', 'pops', 'coms'));
        if (Cookie::get('__urda') == $artikel->id) {
            return $view;
        } else {
            $count        = App\Post::find($artikel->id);
            $count->count = $artikel->count + 1;
            $count->save();
            $cookie = new Response($view);
            $cookie->withCookie(cookie()->forever('__urda', $artikel->id));
            return $cookie;
        }
    }
?>
```

Problem while reading the article.

If you read article A, the number of readers increases.

If you read article B, the number of readers increases.

If you reread article A, the number of readers will increase again. (Should not increase)

example : http://www.jinggacloud.com

What is the solution

Comment: Just use google analytics. They can do a much better job at distinguishing between users.

Answer (score 0):

You can store also an array in the cookie, with all read books. But the user can delete the cookies. Another solution is a database table, where you store, which ip open the video. Maybe you can match these ideas to improve your counting.